# RxJS - Test for empty Observable array

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am learning Angular 2 and RxJS at the moment and feel that this is probably the simplest question there is. I am using the Store to save 'users' to. I want to test to see if this is empty or not from the Typescript side rather than in the Angular template.

Below are the pertinent lines of code.

```
public users: Observable<User[]>;
public store: Store<AppState>;

this.users = this.store.select(state => state.user);

if(!this.users) {
//DO THIS 
}
```

I have tried length, == null, == undefined and can't find how to test for this seemingly basic state. Any help appreciated.

Note that saving and retrieving users to the store is working correctly.

Comment: this.users is observable. It is potentially asynchronous. It can't be used as `if(!this.users) ...`. It should be `this.users.subscribe(users => { if (!users.length) ... })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `Store` works as you indicate, it returns an Observable. So what you receive (`this.users`) is not actually the store value, but rather a stream that will output that value.

As a consequence, to test whether the value is empty, you don't test the stream itself. Rather, you subscribe to the stream and observe what comes out:

```
public users: User[];

// subscribing will actually trigger the fetch for user data
this.store.select(state => state.user)
          .subscribe(data => this.onUsersEmitted(data));

// executed once user data arrives from the store
public onUsersEmitted(data:User[]){
    this.users = data;
    if(!data || !data.length){ /*empty data arrived*/}
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's great. Clearly need to get to grips with Observables rather better. One point is that the if clause did not work. On inspecting Data was an empty array. I used this which worked.

    if(this.users.length==0){

Comment: @Billyhomebase thanks for the feedback. Updated my answer with what I'd do